# Can the word "eitz" mean "a thought" in the Torah?

Tags: words, hebrew, midrash, parashat-bereishit

Is there support in the Talmud or later rabbinical literature to interpreting the Torah term "eitz," commonly translated as "tree," to also mean "thought". This of course, is a common usage in Yiddish, where Eitzos (plural of Eitz) refers to "ideas". If there is such support then could it be that the Bereshis 2:17 (Genesis 2:17) episode in Gan Eden where Adam is instructed to avoid the Eitz Hadas ("tree" of knowledge) really means that Adam was instructed  to not "eat" (i.e., imbibe, engage, or believe in) thoughts which apparently differentiate between "good" and "evil". In other words, the Torah may be relating that such conceptual discrimination led to the expulsion from Gan Eden (Paradise)?

Is there support in the Talmud or later writings to this interpretation?

Comment: though it seems that the masc noun eitz and the fem noun eitzah are etymologically unrelated (Klein, page 480) there is an instance of a fem. eitzah=tree, yirmiyah 6:6 " כִּרְתוּ עֵצָה, וְשִׁפְכוּ עַל-יְרוּשָׁלִַם סֹלְלָה" and rashi (via chabad.org) reads "Cut the trees: Heb. עצה. This is not a ‘mappiq heh,’ yet it is an expression of a tree (עץ), for the expression of cutting is not appropriate for advice, (עצה), and עצה mentioned here is an expression of many trees, as דגה is an expression of many fish." so there might be room for explication.

Comment: Sounds like a question for @RHirch!

Comment: Hersh, while your question intrigues, note that if you meant it just as you asked it then you're laboring under a misapprehension. _Etzos_ isn't the Yiddish plural of _etz_: it's the plural of _etza_, as in Hebrew. And while I'm far from being a Yiddish expert, I suspect that, as in Hebrew, _etzos_ in Yiddish means "suggestions" or "pieces of advice" rather than "ideas". _Etz_ (as in _gan Eden_) is a wholly different word. That said, I called your question intriguing, because of what Dan & DoubleAA mention, that similar words sometimes are related, whether etymologically or in _drasha_.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what your asking. Rabbi Munk on the Torah explains what is brought down in the Zohar on parshas shelach  that the sin of the mekosehes eitzim (gatherer of wood) was really a philsophical debate withinhimself between  the two ways of living.Either living a life of the eitz hadaas or the eitz hachaim and the term mekoshesh eitzem takes on a new meaning(can also translate into the contrastor of trees).

Comment: The Yiddish Eitzos doesn't mean ideas. It's also not Yiddish. It is Hebrew, and it is the plural of 'Eitzah, which means advice.

Comment: Incidentally, Hersh, welcome to the site. I hope you stick around and post many good questions and answers.

Comment: @SethJ I don't know about this case, but the two don't have to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Sam et. al.- Thank you for the reference to Zohar via R. Munk. What underlies my question is the apparent dearth of references in the Torah to the phenomenon we call "thoughts" or thinking or, even, mind. Yes, there's MaCHSHoVoTH but even that is found I believe in only 3 places. We live in an age where "thinking" is so pervasively acknowledged to be happening within everyone that I am wondering how the Torah could have "missed" refering to such a deeply pervasive aspect of everyone's lives! Surely people were thinking and thoughts (just like dreams) were happening 3,000 years ago too.

Comment: This led to a hypothesis that the Torah's apparent "silence" on the notion "thought" or mind was really that we today have lost the correct translation for the Biblical word which means "thought". In other words, references to "thinking" and mind" really *ARE* mentioned throughtout the Torah but we just don't know that. An example might be the word "Eitz".  Additional hint to this hypothesis imho comes from the very name "Gan Eden". The root letters of Eden are EIYIN/DALET or "Ed" which has been passed down through the millenia  to mean Witness.

Comment: Now "witnessing" is a form of "perceiving" perhaps without a filter or bias. So now we have that Adam was in a field of "real seeing" or true perceiving ("Gan Eden") and by entering into the belief of "Eitz Hadas Tov V'Ra" (thoughts which discriminate between Real and unreal or Good and evil) he no longer existed in the state of clear witnessing (Gan Eden). Maybe the Torah is teaching relating a  deep psychological or philosophical insight about "thinking" here.  Hersh

Comment: @DoubleAA, I didn't think what was being asked was clear. Reading Hersh's most recent comments, I'm even more convinced that he is asking the wrong question. Hersh, I think you should reframe the question to focus on how TaNa"Ch (or the Torah specifically) addresses (or doesn't address) thought, and why. You can use your own idea as either a suggestion within the question or as a suggested answer.

Comment: Yirmeyahu 49:30 looks interesting.

Comment: @SethJ What's the "right" question, and what makes it so?

Comment: @eee, the right question is one that asks what you want to ask, not one that asks for support for an idea that you think might be the right answer to the question that you actually want to ask.

Comment: @SethJ Hmmm, that's in tune with a lot of good stuff.

Comment: @Hersh, I hope my criticisms didn't come off as too harsh. Although it is an interesting theory, I think a revision is in order to make it fit with the Q&A format, rather than just proposing a novel interpretation and asking if anyone agrees. Note that [I recently asked a similar question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15911/5), and that I was hit pretty hard with criticism for it. I think each instance is unique, though, and you might be able to make this more in line with the standard Q&A format with a simple [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/16531/edit).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one:

> When the Alter Rebbe was still in Vitebsk he once expounded on the verse "You stand..." (Deut. 29:9). Taking *eitz* (wood) as an idiom of *eitza* (counsel), he interpreted "choppers of wood" to mean that one must chop out "the many thoughts (counsels) in the heart of man."

([Hayom Yom, 19 Elul](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5918/jewish/Elul-19.htm))

Comment: Alex - thank you- OT -- the full quote from Tanya Ch.1 includes "Those who draw water," he interpreted - one must drain out the water that "makes all enjoyments grow."3
Maybe that's why Moshe Rabbeinu was named so -- Min Hamayim Mishisehu - Moshe was pulled from the water  (Even more OT... water "Mayim" in Torah may be refering to what in the east is called "Maya" or illusion/delusion... Moshe was free off Mayim/Maya :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Analytical Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon, עץ is dervied from the verb עצה which means "*to close* the eyes . . . Arabic also *to be hard, firm*." This is also where the word spine is derived from.

"Thoughts," as described above, is separate, and not part of the etymology.

Comment: do you have a link to the book? if not to the actual text, then to the book on amazon or the like?

Comment: [PDF](http://archive.org/stream/analyticalhebrew00daviuoft#page/n5/mode/2up) of entire text. Indispensable resource.

Comment: @Seth- I really don't know where to go with the re-write suggestion as Alex's quote is good enough for me (i.e., it gives precedent for infering Eitz to be interpreted as "thought (counsel)"-- Beyond that, it may be far-fetched to say the story in Gan Eden is about the relationship between pure perception (Eden) and evaluative or interpretive thinking (Das Tov v'Ra) but that's the connection this mind makes and I'm happy to be the only person seeing it this way :)

Answer (score 0):

The basis of the question is a misconception of the roots of the words.

Eitz means tree, and its plural is eitzim.

Eitzah means advice, and its plural is eitzos.

Both words are Hebrew.