# Are there any scriptural sources that Hashem loves each Jew individually?

Tags: sources-mekorot, ahavat-yisrael

Are there any scriptural sources that [Hashem](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1196) loves each Jew individually? I know there are pesukim (verses) that deal with how Hashem treats or views Am Yisrael (the Jewish nation) as a whole, but what are the mekoros (sources) for individuals?

Edit: I find it scary that Hashem's love for each and every Jew is spoken about so often, and is taken (I think) by most of us as a given, but that after several days, still no clear sources for the concept have been found (and I did a lot of looking...)

Comment: By 'scriptual", I can safely assume you mean only Tanach and not, say, Midrash/Gemara?

Comment: does this include verses which refer to all individuals? (like some of the verses in ashrei)? does it have to be "love" or some other form of connection?

Comment: @HodofHod, wouldn't Midrash/Gemara sources be based on a verse themselves? But I would be interested in them regardless.

Comment: @Dan , that would depend if it's clearly meant for each individual separately. I'm basically looking for proof that Hashem loves ME!

Comment: I don't know if he names you, but look through all the statements in Ashrei and see what he will do for each person who follows him.

Comment: @Dan, While the verses do mention the perks of following Him, I still don't see a proof that He LOVES each of us.

Comment: I have to second @Dan here, without referring to the cliche regarding the loudness of actions. The proof that Hashem loves individuals is borne out by what He does for them. Is the word "love" all you're looking for? If so, it may be all the more difficult because that is an English word and none of Tana"ch is in English. The concept of close attention and care for individuals certainly is.

Comment: can you explain what you feel the ramification would be if there were no declaration of specific love, and only a general love.

Comment: Menachem, the relationship with one who loves you is very different to the relationship with one who doesn't. It would also affect many hashkafic issues, like Bitachon (i.e. I can trust that whatever Hashem does is for my best, because He loves me).

Comment: @Shraga: But even if G-d only says he loves the Jewish people as a whole, do you feel that somehow excludes you?

Comment: @Shraga, can you [define 'LOVE'](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15911/5)?

Comment: I assume you are looking for the word Ahavah, correct? May I recommend: http://www.worldcat.org/title/concordantzia-anaynit-shel-hatanach/oclc/697518014

Comment: See Michtav MeEliyahu vol. 1 p. 87

Answer (score 8, accepted):

G-d's counting of the Jewish people expresses his love for the individual Jew (since counting emphasizes the importance of the individual unit. Were the individual unit not important, there would be no need to count). Rashi ([Shemot 1:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9862/showrashi/true#v1)) says:

> **And these are the names of the sons of Israel:** Although [God] counted them in their lifetime by their names (Gen. 46:8-27), He counted them again after their death, to let us know how precious they are [to Him], because they were likened to the stars, which He takes out [From beyond the horizon] and brings in by number and by name, as it is said: who takes out their host by number; all of them He calls by name (Isa. 40:26). [From Tanchuma Buber, Shemot 2; Exod. Rabbah 1:3]

Rashi ([Bamidbar 1:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9929/showrashi/true#v1)) says that because G-d loves the Jewish people he counts them all the time.

(See [here](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/chassidic-dimension-2/13.htm#na6) and [here](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/529017/jewish/Why-Another-Census.htm), where the Lubavitcher Rebbe elaborates on the significance of counting)

Answer (score -1):

"Because of G-d's love for you" ([Devarim 7:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0507.htm#8)).

"His banner over me is love" ([Shir HaShirim 2:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3002.htm#4)).

"Every single person is required to say, 'The world was created for me'" ([Sanhedrin 4:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37945&st=&pgnum=411)).

"A great love You have loved us" (Ahavah Rabah, [Sidur](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/sidurim/ashkenaz/hol/shaharit.asp#3)).

"You are the children of The L-rd, your G-d" ([Devarim 14:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0514.htm#1))

I left this as a community wiki. Add more if you can.

Comment: The first two are expressions of God's love for the nations as a whole, not the individuals necessarily. The latter two are not even scriptural verses.

Comment: @jake Concerning your second point, the author [said](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18523/are-there-any-scriptural-sources-that-hashem-loves-each-jew-individually/18550#comment45094_18523) he'd be interested in other sources as well

Comment: @jake And to your first point: Just before the first line I quoted, it says "*Not* because of how many you are..." And Rashi on that pasuk in Shir HaShirim says that it refers to Har Sinai, in which we were all "ke'ish echad belev echad"

Comment: @b-a, I think that "Not because of" notwithstanding, the expression of love still was said about the nation as a whole. #3 is interesting, but I'm not sure it proves love perse. But it's definitely food for thought. As regards #4, we have no reason to think it's not talking about "us" as Am Yisrael.

Comment: @Shraga 4. Although the expression is plural, the continuation of the prayer is certainly about personal things (e.g. help in learning)

Comment: @ba, source 1 is in the plural, though.